# How to replace a certain character from values of dicts in a list?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

I am trying to replace a certain character from the given list but I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

How I can solve this problem?

```
String=[{"id":"id1 \n\n","key2 \n":"value2","key3":"value3"},{"id":"id2","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},{"id":"id3","key2":"value2","key3":"value3't"}]

new_str = String.replace('\n', '')

new_str = String.replace("'", '')
print new_str
```

Comment: String is a list of dictionary objects and list objects do not have a replace method.  Are you sure you are initializing String to the value you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a `list` of `dictionaries` not a `string`, you need to iterate through your `keys` and `values` in each dictionary to accomplish this

```
lst = [{k.strip(): v.strip().replace("'","") for k, v in i.items()} for i in lst]
# [{'id': 'id1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, {'id': 'id2', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, {'id': 'id3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3t'}]
```

Expanded

```
res = []
for i in lst:
    x = {}
    for k, v in i.items():
        x[k.strip()] = v.strip().replace("'","")
    res.append(x)
print(res)
```

Comment: Hi,@vash_the_stampede thank you so much for ur reply and help

Answer (score 0):

String in your question is actually a list of dictionary elements.
And lists don't have a replace method as well. So that won't work.
Since you want to replace the new lines from each key and value, you have to iterate through each element of the list and each key-value pair of the dict and replace the new lines in the string.

```
list_of_dicts = [{"id" : "id1 \n\n", "key2 \n" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"},{"id" : "id2", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"},{"id" : "id3", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3't"}
    ]

new_list_of_dicts = [dict([(key.replace("\n", ""), dict1[key].replace("\n", "")) for key in dict1]) for dict1 in list_of_dicts]

print new_list_of_dicts
```

Output:

```
[{'key3': 'value3', 'key2 ': 'value2', 'id': 'id1 '}, {'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'id': 'id2'}, {'key3': "value3't", 'key2': 'value2', 'id': 'id3'}]
```

Comment: Hi, Shirish thanks for ur reply and help. can u tell me that how I can replace "value3't" from 'value3't' ?

Comment: Use value3't instead of \n in replace function

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of dictionaries. so we need to iterate the array first. then we need to make a new dictionary with corrected keys and values and then fill in the dictionary with new items.

```
    String=[{"id":"id1 \n\n","key2 \n":"value2","key3":"value3"},{"id":"id2","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},{"id":"id3","key2":"value2","key3":"value3't"}]

for dic in String: 'iterating the array
    newdic = {} 'a new dictionary to stroe corrected pairs
    for item in dic.items():
        'making a new pair with corrected key and value
        key = item[0].replace('\n', '').replace("'", '')
        val = item[1].replace('\n', '').replace("'", '')
        newdic.update({key:val})
    ' now replace the dictionary items
    dic.clear()
    dic.update(newdic)
```